# ImportError in WSGI app with virtual environment

Tags: python, apache, centos, virtualenv, wsgi

I've got a Flask app that runs on a Centos Server with Apache 2.4.6, Python 3.6.6. When I start my app directly through Python, with my virtualenv activated, everything works fine.

When starting through Apache, however, I get the following `ImportError`:

```
File "/var/www/my_app/util/database.py", line 13, in <module>
     import psycopg2 
File "/var/www/my_app/my-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
     from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: No module named _psycopg
```

So it fails to import psycopg2, or rather a submodule of that. When I start a Python console in that same virtualenv, importing the library works fine, from the same path. I don't believe this is specific to psycopg2, as I had the same problem with mysqlclient.

I did check that the virtualenv is fully readable by the `apache` user. What I find strange is that indeed I can't find any module name `_psycopg` in the psycopg2 directory, but then why does it work when I import the library from within the console (or when starting the app through Python directly)?

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Have you tried importing psycopg2 globally (while not being in venv)? `python -m pip install psycopg2`

Comment: Just tried it, but that has no effect. Why do you think it would? My venv doesn't care about any global packages, does it?